# Rotating List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, list, linq, rotation

The question is how to present nicely working code of *DispList* and *RotateList* functions using *LINQ* eventually *Lambda*. Thank you in advance

```
Class CalcProc
    Property Year As Integer
    Property Type As String
    Property Count As Integer
    Property Total As Integer
    Property Proc As Decimal
End Class
Sub CreateListOfT()
    Dim List As New List(Of CalcProc)

    List.Add(New CalcProc With {.Year = 2013, .Type = "A", .Count = 12, .Total = 20, .Proc = calcP(.Count, .Total)})
    List.Add(New CalcProc With {.Year = 2013, .Type = "B", .Count = 22, .Total = 30, .Proc = calcP(.Count, .Total)})
    List.Add(New CalcProc With {.Year = 2014, .Type = "C", .Count = 32, .Total = 40, .Proc = calcP(.Count, .Total)})
    List.Add(New CalcProc With {.Year = 2015, .Type = "D", .Count = 42, .Total = 50, .Proc = calcP(.Count, .Total)})
    List.Add(New CalcProc With {.Year = 2016, .Type = "E", .Count = 52, .Total = 60, .Proc = calcP(.Count, .Total)})
    DispListOfT(List)
    RotateListOfT(List)

End Sub
Private Function DispListOfT(Of T)(ByVal dList As IList(Of T))

    If Not dList.Any Then
        MsgBox("NOTHING to display!", vbCritical, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name())
        End
    End If

    Dim fields() = dList.First.GetType.GetProperties
    Dim ListColumns = (From x In fields Select x.Name).ToList()
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", ListColumns.ToArray))

    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    For Each item In dList
        sb.Length = 0
        For Each field In fields
            Dim p = item.GetType.GetProperty(field.Name)
            sb.Append(p.GetValue(item, Nothing)) : sb.Append(",")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(Left(sb.ToString, sb.Length - 1))
    Next

End Function

Public Function RotateListOfT(Of T)(ByVal dList As IList(Of T))

    Dim sa As New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim fields() = dList.First.GetType.GetProperties
    Dim dCount As Integer
    Dim Modulo As Integer = dList.Count \ 4
    For i As Integer = 0 To Modulo - 1
        For Each field In fields
            sa.Append(field.Name)
            sa.Append(vbTab)
            For Each item In dList
                If dCount Mod Modulo = i Then
                    Dim p = item.GetType.GetProperty(field.Name)
                    sa.Append(p.GetValue(item, Nothing))
                    sa.Append(vbTab)
                End If
                dCount += 1
            Next
            Console.WriteLine(sa.ToString)
            sa.Length = 0
        Next
    Next
End Function
Function calcP(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Decimal
    Return Round(a * 100.0 / b, 2)
End Function
```

`List(Of T)`

```
Year, Type, Count, Total, Proc
2013,A,12,20,60
2013,B,22,30,73.33
2014,C,32,40,80
2015,D,42,50,84
2016,E,52,60,86.67
```

Rotated `List(Of T)`

```
Year    2013    2013    2014    2015    2016
Type    A       B       C       D       E
Count   12      22      32      42      52
Total   20      30      40      50      60
Proc    60      73.33   80      84      86.67
```

Comment: Define *nicely working*. And what's not "nice" in your code?

Comment: Thank you for a question. Actually nicely and working should be separated. Working means I'm not asking for solution, unless someone has got more simple  code, worthwhile to publish. Nicely is linked to using LINQ or Lambda as my code looks like ordinary Visual Basic.

Comment: @NetMage   Thank you for editing the output results. Looks great!!!

Comment: Is there a reason `DispListOfT` is a `Function` and not a `Sub` when it doesn't return a value? Similarly shouldn't `RotateListOfT` return a value?

Comment: @NetMage No reason, it's a just quickly written prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my re-write of your `Sub`s. While you could replace the remaining `For Each` loops with `List.ForEach`, there is no advantage to doing so, and I think it is less clear. LINQ is really best for transforming sequences into results, which you then use for I/O.

Since you know the parameter `dList` is a `IList(Of T)`, you know that every member will of a `T` with the same properties, so no reason to retrieve the properties for each item.

Finally I used lambda syntax for the LINQ as it lends itself to being nested in other function calls.

```
Public Sub DispListOfT(Of T)(ByVal dList As IList(Of T))
    If Not dList.Any Then
        'MsgBox("NOTHING to display!", vbCritical, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name())
        Return
    End If

    Dim props = dList.First.GetType.GetProperties
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(Function(p) p.Name)))

    For Each item In dList
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(Function(p) p.GetValue(item))))
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub RotateListOfT(Of T)(ByVal dList As IList(Of T))
    For Each prop In dList.First.GetType.GetProperties
        Console.Write(prop.Name)
        Console.Write(vbTab)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbTab, dList.Select(Function(item) prop.GetValue(item))))
    Next
End Sub
```

If I were writing a program to do this, I would probably separate rotation of the `List` from outputting the rotated `List`. Also, it should be very unusual to use Reflection to get property names from types, you should already know the types you are dealing with and add the output methods to the class for the type, unless your program is dealing with lots of lists of different classes for some reason.

Comment: NetMage  You're 100% right. I've started with .NET just recently and still learning by example mainly from internet. I'm shocked with the power of LINQ/ Lambda that's why I'm re-writing bit and pieces of purely traditional VB code developed long time ago. But to my surprise many simple modules like those two subs are not available on the net (I mean the way I want to see it). And last but not least I'm retired programmer, and I stopped coding just before .NET technology arrived...